# Apply substring on values in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, linq, linq-to-sql

I am binding the dropdown values using LINQ as below

```
var varResult =
        (from OppData in dtOpp.AsEnumerable()
          select new
          {
           TEXT = OppData.Field<object>(sColName), //column value
           VALUE = sColName // column Name
           }
        ).Distinct();
```

Then the code is converted to datatable using LINQtoDataTable Function.

```
dtTemp = LINQToDataTable(varResult);
```

Then the dropdown is binded as seen below;

```
 ddlTemp.DataSource = dtTemp;
 ddlTemp.DataTextField = "TEXT";
 ddlTemp.DataValueField = "VALUE";
 ddlTemp.DataBind();
```

Now the value that dropdown binds for one of the column, (Employee Joining date) is in format of 08/09/2011~Y, because it is directly getting bind from database. I wish to apply substring on the date so that it is in format of 08/09/2011. How to apply substring on the LINQ queries?

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys, but i wish to apply the change only for one column. This would throw an error for columns other than Employee Joining date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `TEXT` field in your anonymous type in LINQ query as `string` and format value during query:

```
var varResult =
    (from OppData in dtOpp.AsEnumerable()
      select new
      {
       TEXT = OppMilestonedate.Field<object>("EMP_JOIN_DATE") == null ? null : OppMilestonedate.Field<object>("EMP_JOIN_DATE").ToString().Substring(0, 10), 
       VALUE = sColName 
      } 
    ).Where(x => x.TEXT != null).Distinct();
```

Somethign like this. Also you can provide more meaningful format of date representation, ex: Aug 09, 2011, etc.

Comment: Didn't get your last comment. As I know you have only one column in dropdown list and takes text from `TEXT` field and value from `VALUE` field. I miss something? About what columns are talking about?

Comment: We have multiple fields such as EmpName, EmpAge. The change should only be valid for Employee Joining date.How to check for that?

Comment: Got it. And you are using the same method for all fields. In this case or you need to add some `Convertors` class whitch will define if it's `DateTime` object then do the following conversion, otherwise you can put `if` statement for `DateTime` types and additionaly convert it in following way: `varResult = varResult.Select(x => new { TEXT = Convert.ToDateTime(x.TEXT).ToShortDateString(), x.VALUE = VALUE });`

Comment: Aslo, if retriewed object are `DateTime` type then try to use `DataTextFormatString` property of the `DropDownList` control

Comment: not getting your second last comment. can you please modify the code

Comment: I mean if object in TEXT field is `DateTime` type - than you can try to use property of the control for formatiing the value

Comment: Can't i make use of substring function and take the date out instead of using datetime

Comment: Sure you can, `ToString().Substring(0, 10)` if we assume that you need first 10 symbols from date string. But anyway you need to do this as an exception from your usual flow (using same method for all cases).

Comment: i can put a condition depending on column name and could write 2 LINQ queries. but the catch is that the substring also doesn't works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3582/discussion-between-samich-and-xor-power)